# Getting strange reaction in T-SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sentry, sql-execution-plan

I am writing a stored procedure and when I tested the procedure in Execution Plan/Sentry Plan Explorer I have noticed that in one statement the plan reacts strangely.

Here are 2 scripts that from my point of view are the same, but the results are significantly different.

**Script 1** (not real code, but a code that demonstrates the problem):

```
DECLARE @MyVariable INT;
SET @MyVariable = 123456789;

SELECT MT.Name, OT.Name
FROM MyTable MT
INNER JOIN OtherTable OT ON MT.ID = OT.MyTableID
WHERE OT.TypeID = @MyVariable;
```

**Script 2:**

```
SELECT MT.Name, OT.Name
FROM MyTable MT
INNER JOIN OtherTable OT ON MT.ID = OT.MyTableID
WHERE OT.TypeID = 123456789;
```

It seems to be the same, but the results I get are different:

1. Estimated rows in *Script 1*: **15621** rows (wrong for sure, too many rows)
2. Estimated rows in *Script 2*: **205** rows (logical result, probably true)

I think that the SQL execution plan behaves differently when a variable is used in the `where` clause. Why? Or what is going on here? How to improve this?

Thanks

Comment: I think you have the SP the @MyVariable you are passing as parameter. Is it true? And the second is just same as your script 2.

Comment: What you are saying is weird and shouldn't be the case? Can you show the full code where you are passing this parameter?

Comment: @Halmet Hakobyan Yes, to be sure, I made set to the variable, this is not the issue for sure

Comment: @Rahul I will post it later if needed, it won't help because the code is almost the same as I wrote, the difference is in the table names...

Comment: Try first query with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` and you will see difference.

Comment: Probably also see http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/33698/5203

Comment: If you use an **explit, literal value**, the SQL Server query optimizer can use **statistics** to find an optimal execution plan for your query. It **cannot** do this if you provide a **variable** since it's value could be anything - it cannot rely on a given, fixed value - it has to optimize the execution plan for any possible value you could have. Also: if your estimated rows and actual rows are significantly different, most likely, your statistics are out of date and should be updated

Comment: Also try executing the following after the stored procedure definition has been ALTERed: `exce sp_refreshmodule '<sp_name>';` where <sp_name> stands in for the name of the stored procedure.